# Android Jelly Bean Strange behaviour of notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have integrated notifications in my app, and I have handle 2 cases :
Pre Jelly bean notifications with NotificationCompat.Builder, and,
Post Jelly bean notification with builder.
This makes me able to manage big text, and actions in post jelly bean version, and works for 2 or 3 time, but in a strange way, today I got the same result in JB and below.

Code for Pre JB :

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle(nMessage.getTitle())
    .setContentText(nMessage.getMessage())
    .setTicker(nMessage.getTitle())
    .setWhen(when)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ttd_petales)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(pint);
    notification= notif.build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Code for JB and above :

```
Builder bigTextNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(nMessage.getTitle())
        .setTicker(nMessage.getTitle())
        .setContentText(nMessage.getMessage())
        .setWhen(when)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ttd_petales)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pint);
        if(nMessage.getHasPhone()){
        Intent iCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(nMessage.getPhone()));
        PendingIntent pintCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, iCall, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        bigTextNotification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_menu_call, context.getResources().getString(R.string.call_ttd), pintCall);
    }

    String[] recipients = new String[]{context.getResources().getString(R.string.default_email)};
    String subject = context.getResources().getString(R.string.about_offer);

    Intent iEmail = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    iEmail.setType("text/html"); 
    iEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
    iEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    PendingIntent pintEmail = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, iEmail, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    bigTextNotification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_menu_compose, context.getResources().getString(R.string.call_ttd), pintEmail);

    Notification notif = new Notification.BigTextStyle(bigTextNotification)
    .bigText(nMessage.getMessage())
    .build();
    notificationManager.notify(1000, notif);
```

Have you ever encountered such behaviour or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience: I would send the notification and it would show the content text instead of the big text. Then when I unplugged the USB, it would show the big text expanded.

Now notice that when you plug in to USB, you get an ongoing notification: "Connected as a Media Device". Take a look and see if you get the same behavior with some other ongoing notification, like "Searching using GPS". I do. (My test device is a Samsung Galaxy Rush, and its vertical space is severely limited.)

So while the Android [Notifications documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify) says that only the top notification shows as expanded, it looks like there's another rule as well:

**If the notifications list is running out of room, it will collapse even the top notification.**

You can expand the collapsed notification by double- or single-finger dragging, depending on the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for this dummy question, I'm not using emulator to test this app, but real phone, and the strange thing is that when usb debugging cable is plugged, there's no actions in the notifications (JB) and when unplugged, we get our buttons working :) this solves my issue, but I have no idea about this behaviour.