# How to use bigTextStyle in android 4.1 notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I tried in many ways to get the long thext styled notification but just cant reach my goal, pls someone help.

I would like to use bigTextStyle in order to get multiline message in my notifs. Here is my code:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);


        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.loremIpsum)))
        .setContentText(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.loremIpsum))
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent).build();





        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
```

I use Android 4.1.2 so the op version is ok. Every notificaion is a simple one-lined message, and i dont see the whole text. Please help me.

**E D I T:**

Okay i got the long text, but my notif not expanding automatically, i have to swipe down with 2 fingers. How could i expand it by code..!?

Answer (score 2):

You have to expand the notification to see the big text - by default only the top notification auto-expands, as described in the [Notifications guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify).

Comment: It is my top notification, nothhing else on the notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your notification is getting collapsed because ongoing notifications are eating up the screen space. See my answer here: [Android Jelly Bean strange behavior of notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20685986/194032).

Answer (score 0):

even if u set the MAX priority to push your notification to the top
or it was the only notification in the notification drawer
it wont expand if there is no enough space
e.g.
to many "Ongoing-notifications" in the "Ongoing"Drawer or your screen is small

and even if it was expanded it wont show more than 8 lines , so not all the notification will shows up